# Enabling Use Flat Catalog Category giving error No data received

Tags: ce-1.6.2.0

I am struggling with an strange issue that when i enable the `Use Flat Catalog Category` from admin the front is starting giving the following error in chrome

```
No data received
Unable to load the webpage because the server sent no data.
Here are some suggestions:
Reload this webpage later.
Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE): The server closed the connection without sending any data.
```

and in mozzila - > nothing is displaying :'(

Not getting this at all what is going on. Any body any idea about this please help.

Comment: Anything in logs/reports?

Comment: nope .. no error log is generating and no php error is getting raise i have enabled all error log and php errors.

Comment: are we talking about magento or webserver logs?

Comment: webserver and magento both logs contain nothing.. :'( i just checked both

Comment: are your magento loggs enabled?

Comment: Yes they are enabled.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8405/discussion-between-tim-and-ravisoni)

Comment: @Tim i have found the source of problem it was block html cache that need to enable for this after enabling cache and re-index the category flat solved the issue.

Comment: please post it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution to my problem it was block html cache that was set to disable i think it is necessary for flat to work. I have followed following steps to sort out the issue.

1. Disable the  catalog category flat from admin
2. Enable the all cache types especially the block html cache
3. Enable the catalog category flat from admin
4. Re-index the catalog category flat and catalog category products (Re-index all if they necessary)
5. And voila that solved my issue

Hope some one found this helpful.

Comment: None of the cache types are required for flat catalogue or category to work. Most likely the index.

Comment: Hmm actually even i was wondered when i saw this issue solved after enabling the cache because i have checked by just doing re-indexing several times.

Comment: Please mark this answer as solution.